# ¿Cómo eliminar espacios en blanco de ciertos elementos de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Tengo `carros` la cual es una lista, pero ciertos elementos tienen un espacio al final, y lo que quiero es eliminar dicho espacio de manera que al final la lista quede:

```
carros = ['carro 1', 'carro 2', 'auto 3', 'auto 4']
```

Lo intente de la siguiente manera con la función `rstrip()`:

```
carros = ['carro 1 ', 'carro 2', 'auto 3 ', 'auto 4 ']

for i in range(len(carros)):
    carros[i].rstrip()
```

Pero al imprimir `carros` de igual manera sigo teniendo la misma lista con los espacios al final de ciertos elementos.
Espero alguien me ayude, gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que las cadenas son *inmutables*, si tú tienes una cadena como `"Hola  "` en la variable `s` y haces `s.rstrip()`, eso no va a cambiar el contenido de `s` (no puede, porque es inmutable)

Lo que ocurre es que `s.rstrip()` te retorna una *cadena nueva*,  igual a la original salvo por el espacio final. Debes guardar la cadena retornada en alguna variable, o si no la operación no habrá servido para nada. Por ejemplo puedes hacer:

```
s = s.rstrip()
```

Adaptando esto a tu caso:

```
carros = ['carro 1 ', 'carro 2', 'auto 3 ', 'auto 4 ']

for i in range(len(carros)):
    carros[i] = carros[i].rstrip()
```

Lo mismo aplica por cierto a todas las operaciones de cadenas, como `.lower()`,  `.upper()`, `.replace()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @abulafia es muy concreta y completa. Sólo quiero añadir que puedes  utilizar la función `map` y una función lambda que aplique el `strip`:

```
>>> carros = ['carro 1 ', 'carro 2', 'auto 3 ', 'auto 4 ']
>>> carros = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), carros))
>>> carros
['carro 1', 'carro 2', 'auto 3', 'auto 4']
```

Comment: No sería mejor usar comprensión de listas: `[x.strip() for x in carros]`?

Comment: Tanto esta respuesta como el comentario de @DanteS. destruyen la lista original y crean una nueva. Esto puede ser perfectamente válido o no, según lo que necesite el OP. La respuesta que di yo modifica la lista _in situ_, como el código de la pregunta (si hubiera funcionado bien)

Comment: @DanteS. No sé si sería mejor. Sólo que se puede usar `map`. ¿Sería mejor?